# React-Bootstrap Navbar.Collapse with Meteor 1.3 and Mantra

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, meteor, reactjs, responsive-design, react-bootstrap

I created the following navigation component in a Meteor app, modifying from [Mantra sample blog app](https://github.com/mantrajs/mantra-sample-blog-app):

```
import React from 'react';
import { Nav, Navbar, NavItem } from 'react-bootstrap';

const Navigation = () => (
  <Navbar staticTop>
    <Navbar.Header>
      <Navbar.Brand>
        <a href="/">Meteorball</a>
      </Navbar.Brand>
      <Navbar.Toggle />
    </Navbar.Header>
    <Navbar.Collapse>
      <Nav pullRight>
        <NavItem eventKey={1} href="/new-crew">New Crew</NavItem>
      </Nav>
    </Navbar.Collapse>
  </Navbar>
);

export default Navigation;
```

It works normally, and if I resize my browser on my laptop it will collapse normally, but when I open it in a cellphone(physical Moto X 2014 or emulated Nexus 5X on chrome) the navbar won't collapse, I am using Meteor latest version(1.3) with React-Bootstrap 0.28.4, I am also using the less and css files from the [sb-admin-2 theme](http://startbootstrap.com/template-overviews/sb-admin-2/), which collapse normally on mobile, is there any reason why this doesn't work with this scenario specifically?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer, I glossed over I didn't have the meta tag:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

Also, since Mantra encourages using JS for templating, I used [Kadira:meteor-dochead](https://github.com/kadirahq/meteor-dochead) to add the meta tags, I created a meta.js file inside `client/configs` with the following code:

```
import {DocHead} from 'meteor/kadira:dochead';

export default function () {
let metaInfo = {name: 'viewport', content: 'width=device-width, initial-scale=1'};
  DocHead.addMeta(metaInfo);
}
```

And imported it in `client/configs/context.js`